# Mock Service Worker / Node isn't working and I can't see why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api

If anyone can spot whatever's wrong with this code, I'd really appreciate. Not seeing an issue myself, but it's failing.

```
import React from "react"
import {setupServer} from "msw/node"
import {rest} from "msw"

describe("mocking apis", () => {
  const testCall = jest.fn()
  const server = setupServer(
    ...[
      rest.get("/test", (req, res, ctx) => {
        console.log('This line is never run')
        testCall()
        return res(ctx.json({message: "success"}))
      }),
    ]
  )

  test("test", async () => {
    server.listen()
    fetch("/test", {method: "GET"})
    expect(testCall).toHaveBeenCalled()
    server.close();
  })
})
```

Answer (score 7):

I also had this problem. After a while I realized the cause. In my `src/setupTests.js` file I had:

```js
import { enableFetchMocks } from 'jest-fetch-mock';
...
enableFetchMocks();
```

So, `fetch()` was not being called at all.

I made 3 changes to the posted code to get it to work:

1. Import and call `disableFetchMocks()`.
2. Add `await` before `fetch(...`.
3. Change the URL to `http://localhost/test`, to address a test error that said I needed to use an absolute URL.

Here is the working code (cleaned up to AirB&B style by PyCharm):

```js
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { disableFetchMocks } from 'jest-fetch-mock';

describe('mocking apis', () => {
  const testCall = jest.fn();
  const server = setupServer(
    ...[
      rest.get('http://localhost/test', (req, res, ctx) => {
        console.log('This line is run');
        testCall();
        return res(ctx.json({ message: 'success' }));
      }),
    ],
  );

  test('test', async () => {
    disableFetchMocks();
    server.listen();
    await fetch('http://localhost/test', { method: 'GET' });
    expect(testCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
    server.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: 2. Although this answers the text of OP's question, in real tested code, I don't have `await` before `fetch` and am unlikely to add it. What should we do in that case? 3. Likewise, my real tested code does not use absolute URLs, and this is typical. How can I use relative URLs?

Comment: Thank you. for my case I was missing to have the full http://localhost URL.

Answer (score -3):

When you run your tests these run in a node environment, in this fetch function does not exist (it means: global.fetch) for that reason you need to make a polyfill.

I recommend installing the npm package 'whatwg-fetch'

```
npm install whatwg-fetch
```

and use it like this:

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v77fjkKQTH0) could help